# CTCallCenter how to implement effectively

Tags: ios, events, background, call

I am developing a call related application. Need to get events about the call states, the calls are logged and `UI` is updated.

When the application is active - for a miss call I am getting `CTCallStateIncoming` and `CTCallStateDisconnected:` for a received call I am getting `CTCallStateIncoming` and `CTCallStateConnected:` `CTCallStateDisconnected` not getting in the later. Also if the application is in background no events will call. I would like to know how to receive events from `CTCallCenter` in the background at all times and then have that event directly used by the app.

Can somebody direct me, how to implement `CTCallCenter` `callEventHandler` which should work for all above cases.

Thanks

Comment: `CTCallCenter` is not meant for this, It will not work in the background. The `CTCallCenter` is meant for VOIP client to detect call state.

Comment: i don't get you well, wondering if CTCallCenter won't work in background how VoIP client's get call state. can you explain little more

Comment: Well VOIP client keep running in the background. Not all apps can run in the background. This is restricted to VOIP, Location, Audio and accessory apps.

Comment: yea i read that. so if i implement VoIP module to my app, will the problem solve. Is it worth or any other ideas to achieve this ?

Comment: Well unless you app really is a VOIP app Apple will reject your app. What you want is just very difficult and near to impossible on iOS.

Comment: thanks. since you didn't say "NO", can you shed some light. want to give it a try

Comment: No, I can not. Since I've never done something like that.